# Removing statusBar text like iOS Gmail App in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

This question is not to remove the status-bar! Want to remove **the text of the status-bar**.

I wander, how **iOS Gmail App** hide **status-bar text** form the screen while opening the Left navigation panel.

[image]

I can hide statusBar by prefersStatusBarHidden() but it also remove the space of the statusBar bar. So navigation bar looks narrow.

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

**But in Gmail App it hide the text only but does not remove the space of the StatusBar. How do they do it?**

Comment: I updated my answer below with information that should help solve the rest of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works for me.

```
var statusBarHidden = false

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade
    return statusBarHidden
}

func showMenu() {
    // Navigation Menu Code
    statusBarHidden = true
    prefersStatusBarHidden()
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

func hideMenu() {
    // Navigation Menu Code
    statusBarHidden = false
    prefersStatusBarHidden()
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

**Edit**

The `UINavigationBar` needs a pinned height.
If you are using a `UINavigationController`, then I left out two important steps (all done in the Interface Builder).

1. Select the `UINavigationController` and under the Attributes Inspector, you need to deselect "Shows Navigation Bar."
2. Add a `UINavigationBar` to your `UIViewController` and pin the `height` to 55 (or whatever value fits your needs).

Comment: Yes and it does not remove the space for me.